# uchar.h file not found on OS X 10.9

Tags: c, clang, c11

I'm under the impression my C compiler supports C11 since it accepts the -std=c11 flag,

```
$ cc --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

and `uchar.h` is part of the C11 standard, so I'd expect this program to compile,

```
$ cat /tmp/esc.c 
#include <uchar.h>

int main(void) {}
```

But

```
$ cc /tmp/esc.c 
/tmp/esc.c:1:10: fatal error: 'uchar.h' file not found
#include <uchar.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I tried locating the uchar.h file, but the only hits on my system are from iPhone SDK's weirdly,

```
$ locate uchar.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/usr/include/unicode/uchar.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/include/unicode/uchar.h
```

How can I use `uchar.h` on OS X 10.9? Am I going to have to download a new compiler, or am  I misusing the one I have?

Comment: I don't know OSX, but I had similar issues with C11 support making aligned_alloc and various PRI macros available for uint8_t and uint64_t.  Have you tried inclduing `#include <inttypes.h>` after setting `#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS` to get stuff like uint8_t defined, which is what I use.
 `#define _ISOC11_SOURCE                       // C11 aligned_alloc from posix_memalign(3)` or `-D_ISOC11_SOURCE` ?

Comment: Ah, looking under Linux I see `uchar.h` is about unicode support not unsigned char issues which I only have under Linux, not Cygwin64 at present.  So I guess it's a deeper problem about clib unicode support.

Comment: On UBUNTU i find `ucahr.h` on `/usr/include/uchar.h` may it help you, run `locate uchar.h` on your machine

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/sciter-sdk/go-sciter/issues/64) first they advice to find place of `uchar.h` on your machine and second if you can't find or use it they prefer use `unsigned short` instead of header data type something like `char16_t`

Comment: This is source of `uchar.h`  [uchar.h](https://code.woboq.org/llvm/include/uchar.h.html)

Comment: Apple's macOS has neither `<uchar.h>` nor `<threads.h>`.  It doesn't have the 4 functions declared in `<uchar.h>` or any other functions using `char16_t` or `char32_t`.  Code ported to a Mac that needs those facilities must either be rewritten to avoid using them or be supported by conditionally compiled code that provides the facilities it needs.

Answer (score 4):

Apple's macOS (up to and including Ventura 13.3) has neither `<uchar.h>` nor `<threads.h>`.  It doesn't have the 4 functions declared in `<uchar.h>` or any other functions using `char16_t` or `char32_t`.

Code ported to a Mac that needs those facilities must either be rewritten to avoid using them (at least on macOS) or be supported by conditionally compiled code that provides the facilities it needs on macOS.

Comment: So, how can we handle Unicode characters in MacOS with C?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
cc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/include -L/usr/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/lib -licucore /tmp/esc.c
```

If it didn't work, I suggest that you install "International Components for Unicode":

```
1) Install Macports for OS X
2) Run this in Terminall app: "port install icu"
```

It gives you all needed components for Unicode, including "/opt/local/include/unicode/uchar.h"

Then find appropriate options for cc:

```
/opt/local/bin/icu-config --cppflags-searchpath --ldflags --ldflags-icuio
```

Which gives you:

```
-I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -licuio
```

So you compile your program as:

```
cc -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -licuio /tmp/esc.c
```

I'm not sure, but probably getting icu from it's website might also work for you:

http://site.icu-project.org/download

Comment: This is `<unicode/uchar.h>`, not `<uchar.h>` Apple doesn't have uchar.h because it handles i18n differently.