# ERROR: <bits/stdc++.h>, 'cstdalign' file not found, running C++17

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, visual-studio-code, c++17

I'm trying to run a piece of code in **Visual Studio Code**, on macOS Catalina.
The code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    // Create an empty vector 
    vector<int> vect;  
     
    vect.push_back(10); 
    vect.push_back(20); 
    vect.push_back(30); 
  
    for (int x : vect) 
        cout << x << " "; 
  
    return 0; 
}
```

When I try to run the code using the **coderunner extension**, I get the error:

```
[Running] cd "/Users/VSC_Files/" && g++ -std=c++17 helloworld.cpp -o helloworld && "/Users/VSC_Files/"helloworld
In file included from helloworld.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/bits/stdc++.h:57:10: fatal error: 'cstdalign' file not found
#include <cstdalign>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 1.465 seconds
```

**Apparently this is an error only for C++11**, then why am I getting this error? I have the latest updated Xcode version and the latest stable build of VSCode too.

**EDITED AND ADDED LATER**

Also, I would like to add that I manually added the `bits/stdc++.h` file, and that it wasn't there from before.

Also, when I change `g++ -std=c++17` to just `g++` when running, the program runs and shows the correct output. With a warning as shown below.
`helloworld.cpp:13:15: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]`

Is there an issue with the default C++ version in mt laptop? Please help!

Comment: dont ever use [#include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: @yaodav Yes, I realise that does work. But I was wondering why the error I indicated when we use <bits/stdc++.h> was coming. Any idea?

Comment: I'm amazed that a search for `bits/stdc++.h` on SO does not give you an almost daily hit for a similar question

Comment: Reopened. This header is of course not portable, but if it's there, it should work...

Comment: What does `g++ --version` print for you?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat This is what comes. 
`Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Also, I would like to add that I added the `bits/stdc++.h` file, and that it wasn't there from before.

Comment: @Shravan It should've been mentioned in the question. Where did you get the file from?

Comment: In any case, this is not how things work. This file a GCC-specific feature. If you want to use it (you shouldn't), you'll need to install GCC. (The `g++` you have is not GCC, but an Apple Clang in disguise.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat So this isn't an issue of the C++ version installed in my laptop? Because, when I change `g++ -std=c++17` to just `g++` when running, the program runs. With a warning as shown below. 
`warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]`

Comment: @Shravan I'm not sure why it works without `-std=c++17`, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I guess the question is aimed at getting a competitive programming workspace running, not to create a full fledged software project. The comments about bad practices are not that useful in this respect.

Answer (score 5):

`#include<bits/stdc++.h>` is an internal header for the GCC and you are not supposed to use it, it's not portable.

remvoe the `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`
insted write `#include<vector>` and `#include<iostream>`
also remove [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) it considered bad practice
so you code shod look like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{ 
    // Create an empty vector 
    std::vector<int> vect;  
     
    vect.push_back(10); 
    vect.push_back(20); 
    vect.push_back(30); 
  
    for (int x : vect) 
        std::cout << x << " "; 
  
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I realise that does work. But I was wondering why the error I indicated when we use <bits/stdc++.h> was coming. Any idea?

Comment: <bits/stdc++.h> is internal header could be that part of the header files its including are not in the macOS c++lib is also indecate that from the error message - he cant find "#include <cstdalign>"

Comment: I've added some more info, if that helps!

Comment: According to what version of g++ you have 4.2.1 I don't think it supports c++ 11 try updating your gcc version.

Comment: solved the issue, and subsequent issue comes again, so I continue comment out the error line. It worked!

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue. First I installed gcc via homebrew

`brew install gcc`

To avoid conflict with the existing gcc (and g++) binaries, homebrew names the binary suffixed with version. At time of this comment, the latest was gcc-10.

You dont have to copy the `bits/stdc++.h` after this. Just compile using `g++-<major-version-number>` instead of `g++`, which would use the homebrew installed binary instead of the default osx one. For me it is

`g++-10 -Wall -O2 -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test`

To check the binary name that homebrew installed you can look in the `/usr/local/bin` directory because thats where homebrew installs packages.

Also, make sure that `usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH`

Comment: Also, I am not disagreeing with the other comments saying that we should not use `bits/stdc++.h` and `using namespace std;` in our code. I put this here, because its good to know how to make it work if we have to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I too got these error, and I solved these error by commenting out the `<cstdalign>` part.

After you comment out these line it will give 2 more errors - `cuchar not found`, and `<memory_resources> not found`, comment both of them using " //" . It will not harm you stdc++.h file . And it will definitely work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to comment the following lines out in the file `bits/stdc++.h`:

```
// #include <cstdalign>

...

// #include <cuchar>
```

The file is located in `/usr/local/include/bits/` as well as in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/bits`.
I don't know if you have to do it in both files but the first one worked for me!

---

Update Dec 24:
If you use the g++ with the command line, there is no need to move any file into any directory!

For example when I use the command: `g++ custom_file.cpp` it works fine!
In addition you can add `-std=c++11` to have the most needed functions.
Also I **don't** have to move the `bits/stdc++.h` file after Xcode get's an update.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Any answer that recommends either editing or explicitly using the `bits/stdc++.h` header is, IMHO, utterly misleading.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60671901/12165405) answer MacOSX does not have the file `uchar.h` so you cannot `#include <cuchar>`.
Maybe you can download it [e.g. from here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/wcsmbs/uchar.h)  and paste it to the right directory. I haven't tried this yet.

Answer (score -1):

I am sharing steps to execute with sample code for array rotation which works with following commands

```
g++-10 -Wall -O2 -std=c++11 rotatearrayusingdeque.cpp
```

Then a.out file gets generated.

```
./a.out
```

sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int n,r,i,j,temp=0,n1;
    deque<int> v;
    cin>>n>>r;  
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>n1;
        v.push_back(n1);
        
    }
    for(j=0;j<r;j++)
    {
        temp = v.front();
        v.pop_front();
        v.push_back(temp);
    }
    for(auto x:v)
    {
        cout<<x<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now, there will not be any error, Thanks